# How to give subscript in symbols

Tags: subscripts

[image]How can One define subscripts in symbols like phi?
If I use this command
`$\phi$ $_{SB,P}$`
It does not come properly.
Thanks
In this picture the subscript is not clear.

Comment: Combine the subscript with the math term.  Also, use upright for terms that are not explicit variables.  I might use `$\phi_{\mathrm{SB},P}$` if `P` were a variable, or `$\phi_\mathrm{SB,P}$` if it were not.

Comment: Thanks. But the subscript does not come in a very clear manner.

Comment: Smaller text is harder to read, but the "not clear" problem may just be a screen artifact.  It may look perfectly clear on paper.  Other options would be to create your document in `[12pt]` rather than the default `10pt`.  Finally, a different font choice is also an option.

Comment: Its difficult to create the document in smaller font size. may I know how to reduce the size of particular text.

Comment: The default document text size can range from 10pt to 12pt, which is invoked with the class, as in `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`, for example.  Once you are in a document, one can temporarily change the font size with macros such as `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize`, and `\tiny`.  There are comparable commands for temporarily making the text larger.  You should really consult an introductory book on LaTeX, such as L. Lamport's LaTeX User's Guide & Reference Manual.

Answer (score 3):

Because code is sometimes easier than an explanation, I convert my comment directly into an answer.  Perhaps the OP can comment on what the problem is with this approach.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Combine the subscript with the math term. Also, use upright for terms 
that are not explicit variables. I might use $\phi_{\mathrm{SB},P}$ 
if P were a variable, or $\phi_\mathrm{SB,P}$ if it were not.
\end{document}
```

[image]